# Laravel google cloud app engine session issue

Tags: php, laravel, session, caching, google-cloud-platform

Thank you in advance

I have deployed the project over google cloud APP ENGINE, seems everything working

Generally laravel stores cached file and sessions file at `/storage/framework/cache` and `/storage/framework/sessions`, but for google cloud, we use `app.yaml` file for the configuration (Seems same as `.env`), so in `app.yaml` looks like below

```
runtime: php 
env: flex
runtime_config:
 document_root: public
skip_files:
 - .env
env_variables:
 APP_NAME: Demo
 APP_ENV: local 
 APP_KEY: base64:991ihCoj56qE2RiLqaf+LnBdOBfPzaER2cd4d5d4d4 
 APP_DEBUG : true
 APP_URL: https://demo.ue.r.appspot.com
 APP_STORAGE: /tmp
 VIEW_COMPILED_PATH: /tmp
 CACHE_DRIVER: file

 SESSION_DRIVER: file
 SESSION_LIFETIME: 120
 APP_LOG: daily
 APP_TIMEZONE: UTC

 DB_CONNECTION: mysql
 DB_HOST: DB_HOST
 DB_DATABASE: DB_DATABASE
 DB_USERNAME: DB_DATABASE
 DB_PASSWORD: DB_PASSWORD
 DB_SOCKET: "DB_SOCKET"

 QUEUE_DRIVER: database

 MAIL_DRIVER: smtp
 MAIL_HOST: smtp.googlemail.com
 MAIL_PORT: 465
 MAIL_USERNAME: MAIL_USERNAME
 MAIL_PASSWORD: MAIL_USERNAME

 LOG_DELETE:  true 
 GOOGLE_VISION_PROJECT_ID : GOOGLE_VISION_PROJECT_ID

beta_settings:
   cloud_sql_instances: demo-db
```

Here we can see I have added `APP_STORAGE:/tmp`  `VIEW_COMPILED_PATH: /tmp` for caching and storing sessions, so when I am storing sessions, it is not generating sessions file at /tmp, so the session is not stored in the system.

Comment: To start investigating, are there any error messages or log messages available in your project about this?

Comment: Hello @MrTech, thanks for your comment, but there is no error messages in logs, just session is not setting as it should, i mean i can able to login, can use the site but when i logout it log me out but still it just sending me to login page but no any relation with sessions

Comment: To confirm this behavior, can you please provide the steps you took to set up this project, specifically laravel? Are you following along with documentation? Can you please provide a documentation link?